HttpWebRequest: the underlying connection was closed: the connection was closed unexpectedly
While posting the data using WCF service, I'm getting an error intermittently in C#:

Underlying connection was closed


First of all, I suggest that you go and generate a log to take a closer look at the operation of the server and analyze the cause.
Web.config:
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information,ActivityTracing"
    propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add initializeData="..." type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
    name="xml" />
</sharedListeners>
<trace autoflush="true" />

</system.diagnostics>
It generates specific information for errors.

But at the same time, I think it could be that your timeout is too short, or the number of connections and resource limits are too low. You can set it up like this:
<binding name="yourBindingName"
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
         maxBufferSize="2147483647"
closeTimeout="00:10:00"
             openTimeout="00:10:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:10:00"/>

